# JNI - How to convert 'jint' argument to 'unsigned int' C type value

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a jni function

```
native float nativeMethod(int num);
```

That ties to a C function

```
void Java_com_package_name_nativeMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint num)
{
    unsigned int nativeUnsignedNum = num;
}
```

And my C code requires the use of unsigned integers. How can I make this work? Using the code above I get an error: `Using 'unsigned int' for signed values of type 'jint'`. How can I pass a number ( it will always unsigned/positive ) from Java to a C method, and assign this value to an unsigned integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it:

```
unsigned int nativeUnsignedNum = (unsigned int)num;
```

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add that to the question...
I tried it now just in case, and it works, but before it crashed with a SIGSEGV error

Comment: A SIGSEGV will happen for a different reason, and not for a simple unsigned int cast. You should use the debugger to find the line where is crashing, or post the rest of the code which you think has the problem so we can have a look to it.